# Extra secrets created when helm is used

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-secrets

I created a helm chart which has `secrets.yaml` as:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: Opaque
metadata: 
 name: appdbpassword
stringData:
  password: password@1
```

My pod is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: expense-pod-sample-1
spec:
  containers:
    - name: expense-container-sample-1
      image: exm:1
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "--" ]
      args: [ "while true; do sleep 30; done;" ]
      envFrom:
      - secretRef:
              name: appdbpassword
```

Whenever I run the `kubectl get secrets` command, I get the following secrets:

```
name                                     Type                 Data    Age
appdbpassword                            Opaque               1      41m
sh.helm.release.v1.myhelm-1572515128.v1  helm.sh/release.v1   1      41m
```

Why am I getting that extra secret? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Which helm version are you using?

Comment: @EduardoBaitello I am using 3.0.0

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Helm v2 [used ConfigMaps](http://technosophos.com/2017/03/23/how-helm-uses-configmaps-to-store-data.html) by default to store release information. The ConfigMaps were created in the same namespace of the Tiller (generally `kube-system`).

In Helm v3 the Tiller was removed, and the information about each release version [had to go somewhere](https://helm.sh/docs/faq/changes_since_helm2/#release-names-are-now-scoped-to-the-namespace):

> In Helm 3, release information about a particular release is now
> stored in the same namespace as the release itself.

Furthermore, Helm v3 [uses Secrets as default](https://helm.sh/docs/faq/changes_since_helm2/#secrets-as-the-default-storage-driver) storage driver instead of ConfigMaps (i.e., it's expected that you see these helm secrets for each namespace that has a release version on it).

Comment: I would expect that when I use upgrade --install that I see only 1 secret and not 20

Comment: @MartinKosicky Helm 2 always created a new configMap for every release revision. The difference is only that Helm 3 is now using Secrets...If you have done a hundred upgrades, you will have a hundred revisions, and 100 Secrets consequently...You can see some examples [here](https://developer.ibm.com/blogs/kubernetes-helm-3/#release-storage-changed). Worth mentioning too that every time an install, upgrade, or rollback happens, the revision number is [incremented by 1](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#helm-upgrade-and-helm-rollback-upgrading-a-release-and-recovering-on-failure).

Comment: Yes I agree it shouldn't keep the old secrets (I don;t need them anyway)

Comment: helm should create a new namespace and put these annoying secrets there

Answer (score 19):

There is an option to `helm upgrade` to limit the number of old deployment secrets that are kept:

```
--history-max int      limit the maximum number of revisions saved per release.
                       Use 0 for no limit (default 10)
```

Comment: Is this mean that: We can only rollback 10 versions of a release, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is no Tiller anymore in Helm 3. Hence, **release information** is now stored in the same namespace as the release itself as a **secret**.

Which Helm uses as the [default storage driver](https://helm.sh/docs/faq/changes_since_helm2/#secrets-as-the-default-storage-driver).